# HTML element not being printed with python's .text

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.common.keys


def main():



    PATH = r"D:\msedgedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
    driver.get("https://reservation.frontdesksuite.ca/rcfs/richcraftkanata/Home/Index?Culture=en&PageId=b3b9b36f-8401-466d-b4c4-19eb5547b43a&ButtonId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
    #get the website
    list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
    #get all of the items in the content class
    print(len(list_of_elements))
    #print length - for testing
    driver.quit()
    for link in list_of_elements:
        #iterate through the list
        print("iterated!")
        print(link.text)
        print("printed!")



main()
```

My goal here is to print the actual link of each element in the "a" tag of this webpage, and am trying to do it by printing the .text form of each python href element. However it doesn't work for whatever reason.

This is the error that I recieve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\test\test.py", line 21, in main
    print(link.text)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 423, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 333, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 355, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 74, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 96, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\bshai1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=56058): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/de3756264b0c42ab0c85d1af17b282d7/element/a45a2689-b7eb-4290-99f6-7b8ea036f14a/text (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020DF4DFE0E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
[Finished in 21.9s]
```

Comment: what means `doesn't work`? Do you get error? Show it in question (not in comments) as text. Don't expect that we will run code to see errors. Besides we can't run it because you didn't create `driver` and didn't use `.get(some_url)` so we can't also check if this page has `<a>` with text.

Comment: selenium works on references to objects in browser's memory - so don't `driver.quit()` before `for`-loop but use it after `for`-loop. If you close browser before `for`-loop then it doesn't have access to objects in browser's memory and you should get error message for this (and you should show this error in question)

Comment: @furas, I apologize, this is my first time using stack overflow to ask questions, I initially did not include the link as it revealed my location to an extent, I will include the full code along with the error message shortly

Comment: @furas it worked after putting driver.quit() after the for loop, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show FULL error message and you didn't show minimal working code  - so I guess.

Selenium works on references to objects in browser's memory - so don't close it if you still want to get something from browser.

You have to use `driver.close()` after `for`-loop

Minimal working code

```py
from selenium import webdriver

def main():

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://books.toscrape.com')

    list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')

    print('len:', len(list_of_elements))

    for link in list_of_elements:
        print("iterated!")
        print(link.text)
        print("printed!")
        
    driver.quit()   # <--- after `for`-loop

# --- main ---

main()
```